# Adding a system call to Linux kernel 6

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, system-calls

I'm following [this guide](https://dev.to/jasper/adding-a-system-call-to-the-linux-kernel-5-8-1-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts-2ga8) to add a system call to the Linux kernel as an assignment. The system call is pretty simple; its job is multiplying a given number by 10.

The guide uses Linux kernel 5.8.1 but I have to add the system call to the version 6.3.1.
Everything looks fine except for section 2.6 where it says modify the main Makefile and add your systemcall path to it on line 1073.

```
core-y      += kernel/ certs/ mm/ fs/ ipc/ security/ crypto/ block/
```

But this line doesn't exist in the current Makefile. Instead when I search for `core-y` I see the following in line 741:

```
core-y      :=
```

And when I add the path of my system call to the above line the kernel compiles but fails to install.

I tried looking it up in the linux docs but its too technical and I'm not able to figure it out. As far as I searched there are no guides on adding a system call to the current version of the kernel that explain the process in simple terms.

How should I modify the Makefile to link my syscall to the kernel? and are there any additional steps that I need to take?

**Edit:**
The error I get whilst running `sudo make install` is the following even though I ran `sudo make` and `sudo make modules_install` prior to it and they ran fine.

```
amir@99312201:~/linux-6.3.2$ sudo make install
  INSTALL /boot

 *** Missing file: arch/x86/boot/bzImage
 *** You need to run "make" before "make install".

make: *** [arch/x86/Makefile:292: install] Error 1
```

Comment: "the kernel compiles but fails to install" - What **error message** do you get when install the kernel? Add that message to the question post itself.

Comment: I doubt your `make` ran correctly if `make install` is complaining that you do not have `bzImage`. Is there any error reported by `make` when building? Try also `make bzImage`. Also, you do not need `sudo` to compile, only to install. Not sure if that may cause problems though.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Upon running `make bzImage` I get `ld: arch/x86/entry/syscall_64.o:(.rodata+0xe18): undefined reference to \`__x64_sys_mysyscall'`.

Comment: You could easily check whether your source file, which defines the system call (with SYSCALL_DEFINE0), is compiled: the resulted object file should appear in the same directory as the source one. If you have the object file, but linkage gives the error about undefined symbol `__x64_sys_mysyscall`, then the problem is with some **other steps**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like specification of top-level directories in Linux kernel 6.x has been moved from `Makefile` to the end of `Kbuild` file:

```make
<...>
# Ordinary directory descending
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

obj-y           += init/
obj-y           += usr/
obj-y           += arch/$(SRCARCH)/
obj-y           += $(ARCH_CORE)
obj-y           += kernel/
obj-y           += certs/
obj-y           += mm/
obj-y           += fs/
obj-y           += ipc/
<...>
```

So you need just to add a new line with your directory specification:

```make
obj-y           += mydir/
```

Comment: Added directory name to `Kbuild` instead of the `Makefile` but I still get the same error. `make` seems to run fine and I don't see any error messages whilst running but when I execute `make bzImage` it gives me an error message. Are there any sources on how to add a syscall to a recent version of the linux kernel?